# What is the category of High Level Language for PHP

Tags: php, programming-languages

I am currently reading up on High Level Languages.

Imperative

-Procedural

-Object Oriented Programming Languages

Declarative

-Functional

-Logical

Upon coming across PHP I learnt that it some of it syntax comes from java (an Object Oriented Programming Language), C (a Procedural Language) and Perl(I'm not sure what of type Language). So my question is.
**What is the category of High Level Language for PHP?** And Why?

Comment: PHP has it all. It is a mishmash of categories and paradigms.

Comment: It's general purpose language. It can be either procedural, OOP or functional

Comment: Thats a good question ... but it has no clear category. Its a scripting language which can be used in the way you need it, OOP as well as procedural.

Comment: while java is forcing you to use oop style, php doesn't but it is more efficient to code in oop style. My opinion is, depending on your preferred coding method, it can be procedural, or oop.

Answer (score 2):

Like the other commenters have said, PHP is a mix of object-oriented and procedural. It began as a procedural language and later [added OO features in version 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Objects).

Most of the PHP code I see these days tends to be OO. I believe it's the result of widespread adoption of [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) and [PHP FIG](http://www.php-fig.org/) recommendations.